# Writing firefox extension: How to export private key from certificate database? Possible?

Tags: javascript, firefox, certificate, xpcom

I am writing a Firefox extension and am looking for a way to export the private key from an installed certificate.

This would be replacing the previous process of saving a backup PKCS12 .p12 file, then running using: "openssl pkcs12 -nocert -in backup.p12 -out userkey.pem"

Thanks!

EDIT: I can now save a PKCS12 backup using the XPCOM API, I can extract the Certificate, but am still looking for a way to extract the private key (see the openssl command above). This needs to be cross platform...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have given up doing this. Instead I'm writing a python CGI script and sending the certificate and keys over an SSL connection to an Apache server.

Answer (score 0):

If the point is simply avoiding to export the private key manually then you can use [`pk12util` tool](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/tools/pk12util.html) which is part of [NSS](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/). You can export the certificate like this:

```
pk12util -o backup.p12 -n certificate_name -d /firefox/profile/dir
```

That's a lot easier than doing the same thing from an extension. From what I know, NSS explicitly doesn't allow storing the private key unencrypted in the PEM format so you would still need OpenSSL for that.

Comment: The point of this extension is so that users don't need to enter any commands, just a simple click to export.

Comment: I have actually managed to export the PKCS12 file from within my extension, but I still need to extract the private key somehow...

Comment: Firefox uses NSS and as I said - NSS explicitly doesn't allow that.